# How can multiple developers "cache" their Git Personal Access Token on a remote machine?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

Within our team, we need to develop code directly on a shared remote machine. We have a GitHub repo on this machine, and from time to time one of us needs to SSH into the remote machine, to develop code, and perhaps pull from/push to the GitHub repo. Each of us can generate his/her own Personal Access Tokens (PAT) from GitHub, to use when doing Git operation.

On our own PCs this is pretty okay, as we use **Git Credential Manager** (GCM) to cache the credentials (and this is pretty much safe, since one needs to use, for instance, Windows Login information, to access the information).

But then on the (Linux) remote machine, we have a clone of the repo at `/home/user/repository` with its origin remote set to something like `https://github.com/team/blahblahblah`. Then after a bit of search we couldn't find a clean way to get the Git Credential Helper store credentials for multiple users (multiple usernames and their corresponding PAK). We end up having to enter username and PAK everytime (yes we can cache it with a timeout but that's not very helpful).

With GitHub SSH remote, one option was that everyone can have their own secure, password protected SSH key on the remote, so everytime person A wants to do git, they have to provide password to unlock the SSH key. They just need to set the correct author name on Git Config so that correct SSH key gets read.

But we are looking for a cleaner way to do this. Do you know any special tools or mechanism for this?

Comment: are you sharing same linux user account, or different ones? if sharing same one, why not create different users?

Comment: That's a good point actually :) That's how the target system works. The account we SSH into (account@remoteip) is unique, since it holds some other role and information within the system -- long story short, we have this limit that we the remote user is the unique one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use SSH rather than HTTP, and therefore private keys rather than access tokens, you can achieve this easily with **SSH Agent Forwarding**.

In a nutshell:

- An SSH Agent is a program running in the background that holds your private keys in memory, and provides access to them on demand via a local "socket".
- git fully supports this mechanism, and GitHub identifies the user based on the key offered (you always use the username "git@github.com")
- When establishing an SSH connection to a remote server, you can ask to "forward" your local agent (with the `-A` option to OpenSSH on the command-line, or an equivalent option in whatever client you use).
- This allows programs on the *remote* server to ask for private key information on a socket which *forwards* the request over the SSH connection back to your PC.

Since the forwarded agent is only usable while the user is logged in, and the private key itself doesn't need to be copied to the server, this should meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like a good idea, since we use out personal systems to SSH into the target host! I'm gonna give it a shot.